# Convert Array of object to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I want to Convert Arraylist of object to json in javascript to use it in highchart and angularjs.
Can Anyone  help me how can i do that?

data should look like that

```
                                [
                                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                                    ['IE',       26.8],
                                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                                    ['Others',   0.7]
                                ]
```

Comment: You have to show what you've tried so far, and what you're having difficulty with

Comment: well there is no "arraylist" in JavaScript. And I think you need to learn what JSON is. What is the final result that you are after?

Comment: You have an array of arrays

Comment: What is datasource? You really need to explain your process flow in more detail and what parts of it you are having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify(array)` if you just need to create a string out of an array